# powershell set-adcomputer netbootguid

Tags: powershell, active-directory

quick question.  I want to update the netbootguid of an active directory computer object.  The following though doesn't seem to work.

```
Set-ADComputer -identity $someComputerName -add@{'netbootGUID' = $theguidhere}
```

where `$guid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-001CC082A15C"` #a mac address

I get the following error:

```
Set-ADComputer : A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong and how i can correct it?

Answer (score 1):

try declaring the type of `$guid` ( I can't test it now):

```
[guid]$guid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-001CC082A15C"
```

and try:

```
Set-ADComputer -identity $someComputerName -add@{'netbootGUID' = $guid.tobytearray()
```